# Check in UITableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath fails

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

What could possibly be wrong with this code? I have stepped through it with the debugger and for every value of row it goes into the "return NO;" line when running on the device. When running on the simulator it behaves as expected!

`- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"row=%d", indexPath.row);`

```
int row = indexPath.row;

if (row == 0) {
    return NO;
}
else {
    return YES;
}
```

}

I just added this check to the sample code here:
http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/

Comment: i've tried both on device & on simulator - works for me; are you sure you code has (row == 0), but not (row = 0) ?

Comment: Yes, positive. I copy and pasted that code. When I change my compiler from LLVM 4.2 to LLVM 3.0 it starts working! What compiler are you using?

Comment: using LLVM GCC 4.2 still works as expected on the device

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to XCode 4.2.1 for Lion fixed it.